# Tagged for a Rude comment, but I can't see where I commented

Tags: support

[My Rude/Abusive page](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/25618?group=3) shows two AskUbuntu questions that I can't see (or remember) my comments on. How can I verify that they're rude, and learn from them?

Comment: Are you asking if the post was rude or your comment was rude? If you're talking of your own comments, they could be deleted for any number of reasons - rudeness, obsoleteness, ...

Comment: That page shows you your own flagging history. Those are flags you have submitted on someone else's posts.

Comment: What makes you think you were "tagged"? Is it that page you link to or is there something else? That page shows the flags you have raised, as Dan explained.

Comment: As Oli said, that's flags *you* have filed, not flags against you.

Answer (score 5):

As Dan says, these posts aren't things you said, they're things others said that you flagged.

The only flag *against* you was an answer where you started it with an abbreviated swear phrase. You edited it out yourself and the world moved on. As learning experiences go, you appear to have learned that "don't swear in answers" was the way forward and I think you were right.

Answer (score 3):

As [Oli says](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17196/22949), your flag summary page shows your own flags, not flags raised by others on your posts or comments. The other thing to keep in mind is that the filter you applied--which is apparent from the `?group=3` part of the URL--does not show *any* comment flags. It only shows rude/abusive flags on *posts*.

**All flags a user has raised on comments, even if the user selected "rude or abusive" in the flagging dialog, are placed in "comment flags" group in the user's flag summary page.**

With *rude/abusive flags* selected, the filters look something like this:

[image: screencap of filters in flag summary, with "rude/abusive flags" selected but a hand-drawn arrow pointing at "comment flags"]

Yours may not look quite the same. In particular, any groups with pending flags will list a *waiting for review* status, any groups with expired flags will list an *aged away* status, and you may have--or not have--helpful, declined, disputed, or retracted flags in different groups than I do. Within each group, a status is shown only if it (currently) applies to at least one flag you have raised.

Turning on the *rude/abusive flags* filter actually hides all comment flags including those raised using the *rude or abusive* comment flag reason, because they are placed together in a different group (which I have shown with the blue hand-drawn arrow).

---

Here's a summary of the different flag *groups* and what they mean:

- **post flags** (`?group=1`) - Flags on questions and answers. This includes all flag types except *spam* and *rude or abusive*, which have their own flag groups. Tag wikis are also posts, but they don't support flagging.
- **comment flags** (`?group=4`) - Flags on comments, no matter the flag type.
- **spam flags** (`?group=2`) - Flags on questions and answers with the *spam* flag reason. ("Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion).")
- **rude/abusive flags** (`?group=3`) - Flags on questions and answers with the *rude or abusive* flag reason. ("A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice).")

You may have raised flags that aren't listed on your flag summary page, because:

- Flags raised here on meta go on your separate flag summary page on meta, accessible to you from your meta profile.
- When you flag messages in chat, those flags do not appear in the Ask Ubuntu flag summary, because chat is operated separately from the main site.